# Possible php mysqli bug

Tags: php, mysqli

I am not sure this is a bug or not but at times when I retrieving a result using mysql, I get this:

```
$result->fetch_array();

mysqli_result Object (
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => Array (
        [0] => 3
    )
    [num_rows] => 1
    [type] => 0
) Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array
```

And looking at the documentation, it should either return an array or null, not an object. Is this a bug?

A look at that code when condensed looks like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table where id=''";
$result=$link->query($query);
$row=$result->fetch_array();
print_r($row);
```

Comment: What does your code look like around where you get this error?

Comment: Are you printing `$result` or `$result->fetch_array();`?

Comment: Yes, I am doing a print_r of the result from $result->result_array()

Comment: @Devin: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sample code](http://sscce.org/) does not reproduce the issue (which all sample code should do) in PHP 5.3.4.

`$result` is of type mysqli_result. Based on that and the dumped values, you're using `$result` where you should be using `$row`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the return value of `$result->fetch_array()` to a variable that then becomes an array or null.

e.g.
`$row = $result->fetch_array();`
`$row[0]` etc etc.

From the documentation on the [mysqli result object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php):

A mySQLi result is:

> Represents the result set obtained from a query against the database

Comment: No, that wasn't it, Its returns an object.

Comment: What happens when you do a var_dump($row); ?

Answer (score 0):

when i read from MySQL using PHP, i use this:

```
$query = mysql_query("select something from something");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  $msql[$i]=$row;
  $i++;
}
```

and now, i have two-dimensional $msql array with selected values

Comment: The old mysql extension is on its way to deprecation and should be replaced with mysqli or PDO. Also, this answer is off-topic: Devin is asking about why mysqli is behaving a certain way, not how to retrieve values from a MySQL query.